# Store multiple pair token/device for push notifications

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, token

I'm working on a new app and I want to give the possibility to my user to use more then one device.
The app can receive push notification, my question is how to save more device/token for each user, this for send push notification to all the user's devices.

My idea is to retrive "some device ID" and then store a id/token for each device but I don't know which device ID I can use...

Another idea is to create a random id the first time and then send this id with token, this work (partially) until the user clear application data...in this case I need to resend a new id (no problem) but I can't know if I can remove the old id/token

any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need "some device ID"; the push token *is* the device ID. You need to ensure that your backend database can associate more than one push token with a given user account.  This is typically through a one->many relationship between user "users" table and your "installations" table.

You can't rely on your app to tell your backend to remove an old token, since the user may simply delete your app and it doesn't get a chance to communicate with your back-end.

The APNS service will deliver feedback as to which push tokens were invalid (I assume that the equivalent Android service also has something like this).  You use this feedback to purge invalid installations from your installations table.

Comment: Ok but how can i refresh the token when app need to refresh it? If I have 2 token (so 2 device) I open the app on device 1, refresh token is called and i send this token to my server, which token i need to replace?

Comment: Well, you can use something like `identifierForVendor` on iOS to associate a device ID, but you need to handle the clean up anyway, so you could just add a third.  The push token shouldn't change (on iOS anyway) for a given device

Comment: theoretically the token change in some case...apple say that you need to send the token on every application launch. I can't add token without remove the old one because I risk to add too much useless token :s

Comment: if I try to send a notification to a wrong token, I get e generic error or a specific error? in case I can remove the token if I get an error on response....is a correct way?

Comment: The Apple protocol is described here; https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH11-SW1. You get a specific status for a bad token you should remove this token from your table